# Multi-column to single column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame :

```
    parent          0        1      2   3
0   14026529    14062504     0      0   0
1   14103793    14036094     0      0   0
2   14025454    14036094     0      0   0
3   14030252    14030253  14062647  0   0
4   14034704    14086964     0      0   0
```

And I need this :

```
    parent_id   child_id
 0   14026529   14062504
 1   14025454   14036094
 2   14030252   14030253  
 3   14030252   14062647
 4   14103793   14036094
 5   14034704   14086964
```

This is just a basic example, the real deal can have over 60 children.

Comment: Maybe something like `df.where(df.ne(0)).set_index('parent').stack().reset_index(level=0, name='child')` ..?

Comment: Nearly, the return type is float for child_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).
Casting as `Int64` first will prevent child_Id's being cast to floats during the stacking process.

```
(df.astype('Int64').where(df.ne(0))
 .set_index('parent')
 .stack()
 .reset_index(level=0, name='child'))
```

[out]

```
     parent     child
0  14026529  14062504
0  14103793  14036094
0  14025454  14036094
0  14030252  14030253
1  14030252  14062647
0  14034704  14086964
```